# How do I examine function on complex differentiability?

Tags: complex-analysis

Given is $f(z)=\left | z \right |=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

> Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ to be a function that maps $z\left( x,y\right) =x+iy$ to $f\left( z\left( x,y\right) \right) =u\left( x,y\right) +iv\left( x,y\right)$, then if both
>   1. $\dfrac {\partial u}{\partial x}=\dfrac {\partial v}{\partial y}$
>   2. $\dfrac {\partial u}{\partial y}=-\dfrac {\partial v}{\partial x}$
>   are satisfied, $f$ is said to be satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann condition.

I don't understand how to use it on this example, is here only $u$ given?  So it doesn't satisfy condition or?

Comment: in this case,v=0 and u(x,y)=|z|=$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$,then c-r equations are satisfied only at (0,0).but,Also,at (0,0) ,u(x,y) is not differentiable..so,f(z) is not differentiable at (0,0).                                                                 
result:{f(z) is complex differentiable at a point z=$/z_0$ iff f(z) is frechet differentiable at z=$/z_0$ and c-r eqution is satisfied there}

Answer (score 1):

In your case $u:(x,y)\mapsto \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $v:(x,y)\mapsto 0$.

$$\dfrac {\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\neq 0=\dfrac {\partial v}{\partial y}$$

So $f$ does not satisfy the condition.